# laravel orm mult where will cover condition

Tags: php, laravel, orm

my code is:

```
   $type = 10;
   $logMp = new SendLog();
   $keyword && $logMp->where('msg', 'like', "%{$keyword}%");
   $type &&  $logMp->where(['type' =>  $type]);
   $logs = $logMp->where('group_id', $groupId)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($size, ['*'], 'page', $page)->toArray();
```

after i change the code to :

```
$logMp = new SendLog();
$type = 2;
$logMp->where('type', $type);
$logs = $logMp->where('group_id', $groupId)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->toSql();
print_r($logs);die;
```

for easy to dump the sql,

however , the sql is always  like

```
select * from `send_log` where (`group_id` = ?) order by `id` desc
```

and as you can see , the type params is disppear, how can i handle this?

Comment: why  `$keyword &&` and `$type &&`? Maybe the problem is here..

Answer (score 0):

```
 $type &&  $logMp->where('type', $type);
```

OR

```
 $type &&  $logMp->where([['type' ,'=', $type]]);
```

Is this your original code? As setting the $type then using it as an operator for the where doesn't really make sense.

Comment: the $type is a params from frontend, , and  I has dump the $type , and make sure it has value 2

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `query()` function instead of creating a new object:

```
$logMp = SendLog::query();
$type = 2;
$logMp->where('type', $type);
$logs = $logMp->where('group_id', $groupId)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->toSql();
```